# How do I resolve 'Contract' object has no attribute 'filter', in PIL ImageEnhance module?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm having an issue with my code in production. It works locally- I'm not sure how to troubleshoot the issue.

From what I can tell, PIL is the same version in both environments. The Image module works as expected both locally and in production- ImageEnhancement is causing issues.

Locally, the following code works as expected.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhancement

image = Image.open("a.jpg")
newImage = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)
newImage.enhance(1.5)
newImage.save("newImage.jpg")
```

However when trying this in my production environment, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "analyse.py", line 95, in <module>
  processedImage = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(processedImage)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageEnhance.py", line 97, in __init__
self.degenerate = image.filter(ImageFilter.SMOOTH)
AttributeError: 'Contrast' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the code in a try/catch block which only printed the error text. Full trace now added.

Comment: your error doesn't fit to code. Code uses `Contrast` but error shows `Sharpness`. Besides, it should be `ImageEnhance` instead of `ImageEnhancement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class `Contrast` doesn't create image but object which can change image. And `enhance()` creates new image.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhance

image = Image.open("a.jpg")

enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)
new_image = enhancer.enhance(1.5)

new_image.save("newImage.jpg")
```